# Update the key of a Map during runtime in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to filter a list of items from a parent array, into three different arrays.

So instead of writing like this:

```
this.otherList = parentArray.filter(e => e.type === OTHER);
this.adjustmentsList = parentArray.filter(e => e.type === ADJUSTMENTS);
this.sellerList = parentArray.filter(e => e.type === SELLER);
```

I wanted to write in a better CODING style. And I was reading about the Map data structure of ES6 and wanted to try it. Which ended up like this:

```
      const listConstantsMap = new Map([
            [this.otherList, OTHER],
            [this.adjustmentsList, ADJUSTMENTS],
            [this.sellerList, SELLER]
        ]);

        listConstantsMap.forEach((value, key) => {
            key = parentArray.filter(e => e.type === value);
        });
```

where I am setting the arrays I wanted to update as the key, with corresponding string constants.
I was expecting that since arrays are copied by reference, whenever I update the key of the Map, the original array will also be updated.

But as expected, it's not happening.

Is my understanding wrong? In that case, is there a better way to code it?

Thanks in advance.
Stay Safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Map` doesn't make sense here imo. You cannot store a reference to the object property in the key of the map. You'd need to have only the property name in there. What you are looking for to avoid repetitive code could be a simple loop:

```
for (const [key, value] of [['otherList', OTHER], ['adjustmentsList', ADJUSTMENTS], ['sellerList', SELLER]]) {
    this[key] = parentArray.filter(e => e.type === value);
}
```

Depending on the actual values of your constants, you might even be able to derive the key (e.g. `const key = value.toLowerCase() + 'List';`) so that you don't need a list of tuples.

An actual use case for a `Map` would be if you were to look up something by the constant:

```
const listsByConstant = new Map([
    [OTHER, this.otherList = []],
    [ADJUSTMENTS, this.adjustmentsList = []],
    [SELLER, this.sellerList = []]
]);
for (const e of parentArray) {
    listsByConstant.get(e.type).push(e);
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a MAP if you must, but must you?

```js
const listConstants = { other:{}, adjustments: {}, seller : {}}
Object.keys(listConstants).forEach(key => { 
  const KEY = key.toUpperCase();
  listConstants[key] = parentArray.filter(item => item.type === KEY);
});
```

Using reduce

```js
const keys = ["OTHER","ADJUSTMENTS","SELLER"]
const listConstants = parentArray.reduce((acc,item) => { 
  if (keys.includes(item.type)) {  
    const lc = item.type.toLowerCase(); // you can add "List" here if you need
    if (!acc[lc]) acc[lc] = [];
    acc[lc].push(item)
  }
  return acc;
},{});
```

Comment: I like it, but i would use `Array.reduce()` instead of `forEach`

Comment: @Hollyol Like second answer?

Comment: Yes i like it :D

Comment: @Hollyol `reduce` is unnecessarily complicated in comparison to the loop

Comment: @Bergi It makes the code cleaner and easier to understand, when you see `reduce` in the code, you know you are building something with a new structure based on an array, and not mutating anything. On an other hand `forEach` can do anything.

Comment: @Hollyol OP doesn't want to build something, they want to assign three properties on `this`

Comment: @Bergi To me it is the same: building and assigning. But i guess it is just a different code style. Both methods works pretty well.